# VS2010 .filter files and SVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010

Since we've switched to VS2010 we've noticed a new .filters file that apparently contains the filter structure of the project.  We're also using subversion as our source control.

Unfortunately, every time we check in now we end up with merge conflicts if anyone's added a file or filter to the project.  SVN seems absolutely incapable of merging this file type correctly even though it's text based.  It's getting rather frustrating.

Is anyone else dealing with this problem?  Has anyone found a solution?

Example conflict, coder 'a' adds whatever.txt and checks in, coder 'b' adds filter and new .cpp file and updates.  Gets this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Filter Include="filter_1">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{065f6d5d-81b2-4c98-b313-dceb16c24bf2}</UniqueIdentifier>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="filter_2">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{85ef5151-d045-4b20-b1bf-e65d380a3cf3}</UniqueIdentifier>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="filter_2\sub_filter_1">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{90efdbe3-b53a-41fc-9dfb-147df5e7d7f3}</UniqueIdentifier>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="NewFilter1">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{8162b584-12a0-4a05-8cc5-ede4ced07ba3}</UniqueIdentifier>
    </Filter>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="filter_2\file_3.hpp">
      <Filter>filter_2</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="filter_2\sub_filter_1\file_4.hpp">
      <Filter>filter_2\sub_filter_1</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="filter_1\file_1.hpp">
      <Filter>filter_1</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="filter_1\file_2.hpp">
      <Filter>filter_1</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
  </ItemGroup>
<<<<<<< .mine
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="whatnot.cpp">
      <Filter>NewFilter1</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
=======
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="whatever.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
>>>>>>> .r12513
</Project>
```

Comment: I added this tip to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538149/global-ignore-pattern-for-tortoisesvn-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I wouldn't have recommended doing that until the question about how to share project structure without that file was answered.  Since loss of the .filters file turns the entire thing into a flat structure this actually seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: Okay, I'm keeping an eye on this topic to see what the answer is.  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't seen such filter files, what kind of project do you get those in?

Comment: Could you post an example of the kind of conflicts you're constantly seeing?

Comment: I agree with Eamon: What sort of conflicts are you getting? Searching Google Code for examples of filter files ("vcxproj.filters") does not suggest any reason why they should have to be handled any differently than vcproj files in older versions of Visual Studio (filters used to be part of the vcproj file).

Comment: @Lasse: VS.NET 2010 C++ projects use .filter files. I've got a bunch of filter files by virtue of having used 2010 since beta 1 - for personal projects, so unlikely to get conflicts unless I'm lazy checking in - but even so, I've never seen any issues like this, which leads me to suspect it's some interaction with svn-properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're plain xml files like the visual studio other project files - I can't see why they should be any *more* susceptible to conflicts than other project files.

Are these files perchance being treated as binary and not as text?  Merging binary files won't work - check the svn properties to see what mime-type they're set to (if no mime-type is set, you should be fine).  If the mime type is set, it's possible you're dealing with a misconfigured [automatic property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.auto).

Finally, it's possible people are constantly adding+removing files - if so, you may just need to commit and update more frequently until the project settles down a bit more.

You definitely should not `svn:ignore` these files.

Comment: This answer showed a lot of promise.  The fact that the auto property stuff isn't working is no surprise since it appears there is some funky character at the beginning of these things that is not text.  Setting the svn:mime-type for the file to "text/xml" didn't solve the problem though.  Having the svn admin dude try to find the system wide approach and we'll try that.

Comment: If you can access your svn via http - common, since many people use apache to host svn - you can just download the filter file in your webbrowser and check (e.g. with firebug or http fiddler) as what mime type the file ends up getting served.

Comment: Could the "funky character" at the beginning of the file be a Unicode Byte-Order Mark (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? The BOM should not be a problem for UTF-8 or UTF-16 given the way Subversion distinguishes between text files and binary files: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#binary-files. It would cause a problem with UTF-32 since two of those bytes would be zero.

Comment: Accepted this answer not because it solves the problem but it was the best and I had to pick one.  It is a good answer that has sent us down some paths we might not have tried.

Comment: It would have helped it you'd told us more about the kinds of conflicts you're getting. It's hard to solve a problem when you don't have enough information about the nature of that problem.

Comment: It just occurred to me that even though the BOM would not be a problem with UTF-16, such an encoding would still cause problems with Subversion if any characters are encoded as 0x00?? in the first 1024 bytes. What encoding does Visual Studio use for vcxproj.filters files?

Answer (score 2):

We're experiencing this same problem. It's nothing to do with them not being merged correctly due to text/binary status, but rather because of a quirk of the SVN merging.

Typically if one person adds a new file to the project and commits then the diff will be something like:

```
   <ClCompile Include="dir1\newfile1">
      <Filter>dir1</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
```

Meanwhile, user2 adds a new file to the same filter (ie the folder node in the solution tree):

```
   <ClCompile Include="dir1\newfile2">
      <Filter>dir1</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
```

When user2 updates they'll get a conflict

```
   <<<<<
   <ClCompile Include="dir1\newfile1">
   =====
   <ClCompile Include="dir1\newfile2">
   >>>>>>
      <Filter>dir1</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
```

The crucial thing is how you resolve the conflict. If you use the 'Use A then B' option of your merge tool then you'll end up with this:

```
   <ClCompile Include="dir1\newfile1">
   <ClCompile Include="dir1\newfile2">
      <Filter>dir1</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
```

which is invalid XML. Unfortunately VisualStudio doesn't always seem to complain about this (though it usually does -- seems to depend on the precise nature of the change). So you can then end up with some files orphaned from their filters -- I think in this case it'll try to fix it by finishing the first `<CLCompile>`:

```
   <ClCompile Include="dir1\newfile1" />
```

This then means that newfile1 will appear at the top level of the project rather than in the dir1 filter. Once you have some invalid nodes appearing it seems that you'll start to get more conflicts until someone fixes up the project.

So, the solution to all this is that you need to make users aware of the structure of the file when they resolve conflicts, don't just blindly rely on the merge tool. You have to ensure that every entry has all 3 lines: the opening `<CLCompile>` or `<CLInclude>`, the filter, and the end tag.

This whole problem only really exists because of a quirk of the xml in that a conflict will only affect one or two of the three lines. If the XML end tag was on the same line as the filter then it wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

If the ".filters" file is something specific to the user's configuration, then it probably does not belong in Subversion at all. You can make Subversion ignore changes to the file using the svn:ignore property:

```
svn propset svn:ignore '.filters' .
```

The command above will make Subversion start ignoring changes to the file named ".filters".

Another option is to force Subversion to treat the ".filters" file as a binary file:

```
svn propset svn:mime-type 'application/octet-stream' .filters
```

The command above will cause the ".filters" file to be treated as a binary file and will not be merged.

**Edit**
Now that you've explained that the ".filters" file is essential to the project and also that the problem may be that it is being treated as binary instead of as plain text, the solution is to set the type to plaintext:

```
svn propset svn:mime-type 'text/plain' .filters
```

Comment: This is the same answer someone else gave and then deleted.  Losing the filters in a project results in a totally flat project structure so that all files appear at the top level.  It's not going to work for even small projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer this regarding the purpose of the `.vcxproj.filters` file:

When I create a C++ project with Visual Studio 2010, Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel, it generates a file named `ReadMe.txt` in the project folder that includes this text:

```
<YourProjectName>.vcxproj.filters
    This is the filters file for VC++ projects generated using an Application Wizard.
    It contains information about the association between the files in your project 
    and the filters. This association is used in the IDE to show grouping of files with
    similar extensions under a specific node (for e.g. ".cpp" files are associated with the
    "Source Files" filter).
```

So, indeed, this confirms that the `.vcxproj.filters` file governs the folder structure that you see in Solution Explorer.