# Using git for VS2010 project: Can't add file *.opensdf

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio-2010

I'm using git to track a C++ project in VS2010. I'm using ignore patterns found on stackoverflow, which usually do not exclude the *.opensdf file. Unfortunately, when trying to commit the file, I get the following error:

```
error: open("foo.opensdf"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file foo.opensdf
fatal: adding files failed
```

Why do I get this error and how can it be avoided? Since I'm quite a newbie with VS2010, what is the use of this file?

Thanks!

mort

Answer (score 57, accepted):

*.opensdf is a temporary file opened only while .vcxproj/.sln is loaded to Visual Studio IDE.  It should be added to your .gitignore file.

See the accepted answer on this question: [What should be contained in a global source code control ignore pattern for Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538149/what-should-be-contained-in-a-global-subversion-ignore-pattern-for-visual-studio)

Comment: There is a community `gitignore` file which is kept up to date: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/f51f0baa5a721f0af6fbf0ae377ecd86c6eaa3b4/VisualStudio.gitignore