# Visual Studio 2015 & Git error: open("somefile.VC.opendb"): Permission denied fatal: Unable to process path myfile.VC.opendb

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

**Setup:**

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015 with update
- Running in Administrator mode

---

I cannot commit my changes using Visual Studio 2015 because the commit option does not appear.

When I go to the source folder and try to commit from there, I have n changed files and so I click "**Stage Changed**" which brings up a dialogue "**Stage *`n`* untracked files?**", to which I click "**Yes**".

I am then presented with a failure error:

> error: open("myfile.VC.opendb"): Permission denied fatal: Unable to
>   process path myfile.VC.opendb

Where `myfile` is just the name of some arbitrary file.

However, if I close the solution and then try commit from the folder, it all works as intended...

What is going on here? I have all the updates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using git for VS2010 project: Can't add file \*.opensdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088398/using-git-for-vs2010-project-cant-add-file-opensdf)

Comment: Almost duplicate. Same issue, different extension.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `.opendb` file was added in Visual Studio 2015 update 1, but was not added to the default `.gitignore` file until after the release of update 1.

You can use the updated version, [found here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/f51f0baa5a721f0af6fbf0ae377ecd86c6eaa3b4/VisualStudio.gitignore), the `.opendb` extension was added on Dec 1 2015:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 16):

I also had this problem going from Visual Studio Express 2013 to Visual Studio Community 2017, for the same reason. I found this question and answer useful, but resolved it slightly differently.

I deleted the .gitignore file (actually, just moved it out just in case this didn't work) and in the Team Explorer window, went to Settings / Git / Repository Settings / Ignore and Attributes files. Under "Ignore file"  it said "There was no .gitignore file found", and next to it there was an "Add" button. Clicking "Add" generated the default VSC 2017 .gitignore file and resolved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem on the Team Explorer-Home go to settings -> repository settings-> Ignore & Attributes File -> **click on add** then on Team Explorer-Home-> global settings -> **enable push -- force** and that worked for me .

Comment: Enabling force push shouldn't be needed for that.