# Git pending changes not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, git

I was trying to use GIT for my first project, but after committing the different files of my project, an icon of a lock is displayed on the left side of each file of my project. There used to have a yellow plus icon there, which was a good sign. After committing, I'm supposed to have them all checked, which is not the case.

PS: I ' m currently working on Windows and VS2010. The source control is OK, downloading the specified programs / extensions has been done correctly.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Edit: This is the error that is displayed:

```
Stage 2 files
error: open("test.opensdf"): Permission denied
fatal: Unable to process path test.opensdf
Done
```

Comment: Does everything work as expected? Yes? Then it's probably just a Windows-style hickup. Otherwise, find the logs and post relevant lines here.

Comment: @arne Does KDiff might be the problem? It is stated on the checklist that the path to kdiff.exe is not configurated, even though all the other checklists are Green.

Comment: Well then that might be the problem, although I'm not so well-versed in git on windows; I'm not sure whether kdiff is really necessary for git to work. Apart from that: Can you commit changes to your git? Revert local changes? Other git operations?

Comment: @Arne my question is edited. Please see above.

Comment: Can you check file permissions on the files? Do you have access to them? Do you have access to the git metadata directory?

Comment: @arne I have access to my cpp and h files on that project and of course I can delete and add in them whatever I want. But it seems that Git cannot access them!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34158/discussion-between-melmed-and-arne)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the file `test.opensdf` that is mentioned in the error message is a Visual studio-generated temporary file that shouldn't be in the repository anyway. These files are not shown in VS's file browser, so you'll have no chance to somehow exclude them there. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2539084/818924) for a list of patterns you should ignore when using VS with git. Just add the list to the `.gitignore` file in the base directory of your repo and you should be good to go.